# Best place to keep files that are called by cron jobs?

Tags: plugin-development, cron, rest-api

I am interesting in setting up a Wordpress Website which needs to keep updating certain custom database tables after fetching data from RESTful Web Services, lets say once in a day.

I can achieve this by having a script to make request to REST API, process data and then store it into required tables.

**However, I am not sure where to put this script file so cron can call it without any issues (security wise)**

- Can I place these script files at root level of wordpress directory (such as `/script1.php`, `script2.php` etc)?
- Or I create a plugin of the script, would cron be able to access this file placed inside a plugins directory?

**UPDATE**

1. There will be multiple scripts used by cron, therefore, I want to make plugins out of each script.. Would cron be table to access files in the plugins directory?

Anyone who can help?

Comment: Use the script the WordPress API, the Cron of WordPress or functions? If not, leave outside the installation, is not in the context of this WP install.

Comment: There will be multiple scripts used by cron, therefore, I want to make plugins out of each script.. Would cron be table to access files in the plugins directory?

Comment: @bueltge: I am talking about Cron Jobs, not the wordpress cron.

Comment: Then outside the web root, because security issues. Also is it not in the context with the installation.

Comment: If you are running cron jobs then you should place those files outside web root. A place where these files cannot be accessed directly from browser.

Comment: you should not make direct requests to plugin PHP files, instead use the WordPress REST API and register endpoints so you have nice pretty URLs to query with schema and official support that you can then use hooks with

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running cron jobs under your user account, it will have access to any folder that your account has read access to. If you do not need them to be publicly accessible, and you have access to a folder outside your public web root, then for security purposes you should put them outside of the web root.

However, if you are on shared hosting, this may not be possible due to `open_basedir` restrictions. In that case, you can either create a subdirectory under your main Wordpress directory, or in your plugins folder. You can add an htaccess file to block access from the outside.